# Решение системы нелинейных уравнений(Python)

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scipy, sympy

Доброго времени суток,
пытаюсь решить систему нелинейных уравнений.
Задаю массив символьных значений (sympy):

```
 A=[]
 for i in range(26):
      i=str(i)
      A.append(symbols('a'+i, real=True))
```

Строю саму систему(логистическая регрессионная модель):
Здесь X1 np.array исходных числовых данных (750 строк, 26 столбцов)

```
def summ(A,X1):
    s=0
    summa=[]    
    for i in range(750):
        for j in range(26):
            s=s+A[j]*X1[i][j] 
        s=(1/(1+sp.exp(-s)))
        summa.append(s)
        s=0
    return summa

def l(X1,A,Y1,summa):
    l=0
    for i in range(750):
        l= l+Y1[i]*sp.log(summa[i])+(1-Y1[i])*sp.log(1-summa[i])    
    return l

def proizv(f,A):
    expr=[]
    for i in range(26):
        expr.append(diff(f,A[i]))
    return expr

summa=summ(A,X1)
summa=list(summa)
L1=l(X1,A,Y1,summa)
P=proizv(L1,A)
```

В результате получаю список P, состоящий из производных по каждому неизвестному значению A, элементы списка типа .

Дальше пытаюсь решить полученную систему nonlinsolve(P,A) из sympy, но программа выполняется какое-то очень долго время (после 30 минут просто остановила программу).
Дело в том, что не хватает мощности компьютера?
И, может, кто-то знает как преобразовать данные, чтобы использовать scipy?

Comment: элементы списка P типа <class 'sympy.tensor.array.dense_ndim_array.ImmutableDenseNDimArray'>